# Laravel 5 on google app engine gae :file_get_contents(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, laravel-5.1

after i deployed my laravel 5.1 app on google app engine , the following error appears:

```
ErrorException in main.php line 466: file_get_contents(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(../../public/app/v002/scripts/services/LocaleService.js) is not within the allowed path(s): (/base/data/home/apps/s~awbiz-rc/1.391341546460118921/;/base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk;/php_runtime/versions;/etc)
```

any help ?

Comment: How did you deploy it? Did you use the GoogleAppEngineLauncher?

Comment: yes , deployment success